# Using findById to find the id of a schema in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hey I was wondering how do I use findById for a schema inside an array? For example, I have the following Schema:

```
  const GameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  users: [
    {
      user: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      role: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['user', 'moderator', 'creator'],
        default: 'user',
      },
    },
  ]
}]
```

I want to find the user with a mongoose function like findById, such as the following:

```
  const user = await game.users.findById({ user: req.user.id })
```

It doesn't seem to work since users is not a mongodb model. I know I can find the user by using find() like the following:

```
const user = await game.users.find(
  (gameUser) => gameUser.user == req.user.id
)
```

The only problem is that the type of gameUser and req.user.id is not the same and I can't use '==='. Is there some way to go through the array and use the mongoose function findById?

Answer (score 0):

As [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) explains, `findById` method:

> Finds a single document by its _id field

So you have to use `findOne()` instead of `findById()`.

Also, to return only one field from the entire array you can use [`projection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) into find.

Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ootAW3TaT5c) example. This query find an object by its id (i.e. `user` field) and return only the object, not the whole array.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "users": { "$elemMatch": { "user": 1 } }
},
{
  "users.$": 1
})
```

Using mongoose you can do:

```js
yourModel.findOne(({
  "users": { "$elemMatch": { "user": 1 } }
},
{
  "users.$": 1
})).then(result => {
  console.log(result)
}).catch(e => {
  // error
})
```